# ASM to create java class

Tags: java

I am trying to use ASM to create a simple class file

I have tried as follows:

```
    ClassPrinter c = new ClassPrinter();
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(new FileInputStream("path/to/class"));
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS|ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
    cw.newClass("MyClass");
    cw.newField("owner", "value", "I");
    cr.accept(c, 0);
    for(String s : c.values){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    ClassReader writerReader = new ClassReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\generated.class"));
    writerReader.accept(cw,0);
```

However there is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when creating the ClassReader.

C:\generated.class is as of now an empty file.

ClassPrinter is a visitor that simply traverses all the entities and prints them using system.out.println

How can this be done?

I need to be able to create classes from scratch not just append to already existing ones.

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to never write the file "C:\generated.class"

What is cr and what is c in your code fragment?

Looks like something like this is missing before you open the reader:

```
String filename = "C:\\generated.class"; 

// Generate class

System.out.println("Generating MyClass");
ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS|ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
cw.newClass("MyClass");
cw.newField("owner", "value", "I");

// Print generated class to STDIO to see that is generated as expected

System.out.println("Generated:");
ClassPrinter cp = new ClassPrinter();
cp.accept(cw, 0);

// Write the generated class to a file

System.out.println("Writing " + filename);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
os.write(cw.toByteArray());
os.close();

// Read the file back

System.out.println("Reading " + filename);
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\generated.class"));

// Print the class 

System.out.println("Read");
cr.accept(c, 0);
cr.accept(cw,0);
```

Comment: I added this and the writerReader is beign generated fine, but when I accept I get anull pointer exception. Note that the file that was written, if read using ASM results in null extends null { }

Comment: Not exactly sure what went wrong in your code, but you seem to create the reader before the class was written. I have extended the example to be more complete.